# Map through array that includes object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Below is the response coming back. I'm trying to map through the logo object so that I can grab the url, however my implementation on Object.keys is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
[
  {
    "title": "Header",
    "logo": {
      "metadata": {},
      "sys": {},
      "fields": {
        "title": "Logo",
        "file": {
          "url": "xxxxxx",
          "details": {},
          "fileName": "logo.png",
          "contentType": "image/png"
        }
      }
    },
    "links": []
  }
]
```

```js
{Object.keys(header.logo.fields.file).map((logo) => (
    <p>{logo.url}</p>
))}
```

Comment: assuming `header` is the thing you show us above your code, that's an array not an object, so you need `header[0].logo.fields.file` etc

Comment: Although that's not the only problem in your expression, based on the data you show us, and it's really not clear what you want to be returned.

Comment: Object.keys iterates through all the keys in the object, so your map inner function receives the values "url", "details", "fileName" and "contentType" - none of those strings have a `.url` property (they are just strings).

Comment: Sorry I should have stated what I'm trying to return back, but essentially it's the value of the keyname 'url'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the top-level array name is `header`, just do this. Note that the top-level structure is an array, so you need an index to get the object inside.

```
<p>{header[0].logo.fields.file.url}</p>
```